# How to compare a target-string to other strings(in a loop) while also counting wrong/more/less characters

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

It should print how many wrong or more or less letters the non target-string  in comparison.
Using C code.

my best try so far...

```
Value=strcmp(WordToCheck,OtherWords);
   if(Value==0){
   printf("%s is correct\n" ,OtherWords);}
   else{
        for(k=0; k < OtherWords[WORDSIZE]; k++)
        if(k > Value)
        k++;
        printf("%d", &k);}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of something that compiles or otherwise issues a clear warning or error. Include an example of the expected out of your program for the given input. It is unclear what *"how many wrong or more or less letters the non target-string in comparison."* means - please clarify. Note that [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) already returns positive and negative values, or zero, depending on the ordering of the strings.

Comment: Note: `printf("%d", &k);` invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) - the `printf` specififer `%d` expects an `int`, not the address of a variable.